# How do I instantiate a pug mixin with arguments from javascript?

Tags: javascript, pug

Apologies if this is a basic question but I cannot seem to find information about this anywhere. I currently have a pug mixin defined as such:

```
mixin species(id)
```

I would like to have a button that instantiates new versions of the mixin with ascending ids and adds them to a container element (i.e. I want an onClick to perform "+species(id)"). How would I accomplish this?

Thanks.